# Why gcc is allowing more than two characters of input to a char array of length 2?

Tags: c, arrays, gcc

I was explaining the basic C data types and how they work to someone and when i tumbled across char array i created a char array of length 5 for name and i claimed to him that you can not input your name because his name is of length 7 but eventually it happened , 
and i am clueless how this happened 
Can please someone explain this behaviour to me that how this happened ?

This is the code that i used

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main(){
    char a[2] ; 
    scanf("%s",&a);
    printf("%s",a); 
}
```

Comment: It is taking string input of length 24 chars

Comment: UB͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏

Comment: It's called ["undefined behavior"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  The fix is to not write code that results in undefined behavior.

Comment: `scanf("%s")` is just another name for the infamously unsafe `gets`.

Comment: This would be why `scanf` is usually frowned at in production code. `fgets()` is more commonly used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply got undefined behavior.

In your code there's no way for `scanf()` to know the maximum size (how could it, it's just a function) and it will just assume you know what you're doing.

To prevent this, pass the information:

```
const size_t got = scanf("%1s", a);
if(got == 1)
  printf("Read '%s'\n", a);
```

Note that the return value of `scanf()` is a good thing to check before relying on the variable(s) having valid values. It can fail.